# Refresh UI on ApplicationShouldTerminate

Tags: c#, cocoa, mono, monomac

I have a trouble, when i try to update the text of a button at time to exit from the application.

The `ApplicationShouldTerminate` method is like this:

```
        public override NSApplicationTerminateReply ApplicationShouldTerminate (NSApplication sender)
    {
        this.mainWindowController.EndApp();
        return NSApplicationTerminateReply.Now;
    }
```

And the `EndApp()` method is like this:

```
        public void EndApp ()
    {
        this.testButton.Title="Closing App";
        //long time process
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            int a=1;
        }
    }
```

How can i get that the application refresh the UI Controls??

Comment: whatever you do in that for loop is done on the main thread. in other words, it will just block your UI until it's done, and it will exist right after. can you execute your long time process on a background thread?

Comment: @Haxx The for loop is for demonstrate that i have a long time process, in my real application i use a background process and i have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `Application.DoEvents()` after the title change or in the for loop depending on if you have other actions going on. This forces the application to handle events in the queue, which in this case would be a text change for your title.

```
public void EndApp ()
    {
        this.testButton.Title="Closing App";
        Application.DoEvents();
        //long time process
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            int a=1;
            //or if you're processing stuff
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```